# Taking a leave of absence

Tags: work-environment, australia

I would like to take a leave of absence due to work related issues causing me a mental illness (depression).

How do I go about this situation?

Comment: We need a lot more information to help. What country are you in, your industry etc.

Comment: Australia. Community service (domestic violence service)

Comment: Do you have enough days off (+ medical leave, which would probably require a doctors note) available for this? Do you plan on going back to the same company afterwards? Do you have a fixed end date in mind for your leave? But this would mostly come down to just asking the company if you can take the time off, or resigning if you don't intend to go back - not much for us to say about that really.

Comment: I will be going back to the company afterwards. So you saying that depression is not mental illness and will not qualify for leave LOA

Answer (score 3):

If you're working in a community service industry (especially one concerned with domestic violence), then you're surely going to have resources to help employees out with these situations.

Either talk to your manager about this, or seek out the appropriate resources using your employment handbook or web portal/intranet service.

Failing this, talk to your doctor and ask for guidance.

Comment: +1 dealing with such an emotive (and rather grim at that) subject. I'd be surprised if the organisation didn't have some procedures or policies in place to handle this sort of thing so talking it over with them is the best place to start. Depression is awful so I hope the OP can get what he needs to get better.